# Using an HTML select list as link list

Tags: html, list, drop-down-menu

I have seen some solutions on how to use a dropdown list in HTML as a combo link list with JS. Is there possibly a way to do it without JS directly with HTML?

Maybe sth with method="link"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JS? Yes, do it server side (issuing an HTTP redirect in response to a form submission)

Directly with HTML? No.

It isn't a nice UI design though. Having links people can see without clicking, and can activate with a single click is much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the input Quentin. I have a list of items generated by PHP and the HTML select list serves as a filter. To keep everything clean, I now decided to convert it into a link list, but still it only filters items. I just call different PHP files that then show the selection. Any thoughts/recommendations on that?